# Check Admin or non admin users in nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, registry, regedit

I have built node.js app to set the registry at system or at user level. I need check if user has admin privilege, depending on this, I will set the registry value  at system or at user level.

How I check this in my node.js or javascript code.

This is how I set the registry using regedit

**for non-admin I set HKCU\Environment**

```
regedit.putValue({
      'HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment': {
        'XYZ': {
              value: regValue,
              type: 'REG_SZ'
            }
         }
        },function(err) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the `net session` command as it will only execute if you have administrator permission. Note that this is only for Windows!

```js
var platform = require("os").platform();

if (platform == "win32" || platform == "win64") {
    require('child_process').exec('net session', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err || !(stdout.indexOf("There are no entries in the list.") > -1)) {
            console.log("You are not running this application as administrator");
        } else {
            console.log("This is being ran with administrator privileges!");
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("Unknown");
}
```

With admin: `This is being ran with administrator privileges!`

Without admin: `You are not running this application as administrator`